# Get local name of network share in Delphi

Tags: delphi

How do I get the local name of a network share in Delphi?

I have a Filepath to the local alias of the network share `Z:\someFolder\someFile` and am able to expand the UNC path `\\server\sharename\someFolder\someFile`. However, I need the local path on the remote location `F:\sharedFolder\someFolder\someFile`

Thank you in advance

Comment: You mean the path local to the remote machine where the folder is located?

Comment: yes, is this possible in any way?

Comment: I would have said the same as @SilverWarior.  However, the writer of this blog seems to think that it is: http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2009/03/05/get-local-path-from-unc-path/

Comment: @MartynA Have you tested this? That article is rather old (March 2009). Based on my opinion being able to retrieve such information is potentional security risk. And if someone at Microsoft  might hade same thoughts they probably isued some security fix to prevent this.

Comment: @SilverWarior:  No, I haven't tested it, I just noticed it googling around the OP's q.  I agree it's a potential security hole and it may have been plugged subsequently (but if that were true of all MS's security holes they wouldn't have the need for their endless stream of updates) and even if it works now it may stop working in the future.  But then we don't know the OP's operating environment ...

Comment: @user what is your motivation?

Comment: @MartynA there's no security hole, you just need to have sufficient rights to the server. If you don't have them you are out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a small example:

```
program test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

const
  netapi = 'netapi32.dll';
  NERR_Success = 0;
  STYPE_DISKTREE  = 0;
  STYPE_PRINTQ    = 1;
  STYPE_DEVICE    = 2;
  STYPE_IPC       = 3;
  STYPE_TEMPORARY = $40000000;
  STYPE_SPECIAL   = $80000000;

function NetApiBufferFree(Buffer: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall; external netapi;
function NetShareGetInfo(servername, netname: PWideChar; level: DWORD; out bufptr: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
  external netapi;

type
  PShareInfo2 = ^TShareInfo2;
  TShareInfo2 = record
    shi2_netname: PWideChar;
    shi2_type: DWORD;
    shi2_remark: PWideChar;
    shi2_permissions: DWORD;
    shi2_max_uses: DWORD;
    shi2_current_uses: DWORD;
    shi2_path: PWideChar;
    shi2_passwd: PWideChar;
  end;

function ShareNameToServerLocalPath(const ServerName, ShareName: string): string;
var
  ErrorCode: DWORD;
  Buffer: Pointer;
begin
  Result := '';

  ErrorCode := NetShareGetInfo(PWideChar(ServerName), PWideChar(ShareName), 2, Buffer);
  try
    if ErrorCode = NERR_Success then
      Result := PShareInfo2(Buffer)^.shi2_path;
  finally
    NetApiBufferFree(Buffer);
  end;
end;

procedure Main;
begin
  Writeln(ShareNameToServerLocalPath('\\MyServer', 'MyShare'));
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      ExitCode := 1;
      Writeln(Format('[%s] %s', [E.ClassName, E.Message]));
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible I'm afraid.

Whenever you share some folder over the network you can only get its name, its file structure and the structure of its subfolders. But you can't get any information about its parent folder and definitely not the whole directory structure of the hard disc on which the folder is physically located.

In fact the shared folder might not even be physically present on the computer from which it is shared. It can be a subfolder from some other shared network drive that some other computer shares.

Comment: Not the answer I hoped to hear, but I can see it makes sense, also from a security perspective.

Comment: It is possible if you have sufficient rights to the server.

Comment: I don't think you can share another computer's share.