# Delphi ExpandUNCFilename in reverse?

Tags: delphi

I need what amounts to the inverse of the ExpandUNCFilename function: given a UNC name to a file on a network computer, I need the drive-letter-relative filename for that file as it is known locally on that network computer.  For example, if I pass in "\\SVR1\SHARE1\Subdir\File.nam", and assuming that "SHARE1" maps to actual path "C:\ProgramData" on "SVR1", I would get "C:\ProgramData\Subdir\File.nam" returned.

(Why do I need this?  Because Firebird requires its FDB filenames to be localized relative to the machine the server is running on, but I need the UNC name for other things - I'd prefer to just store and pass the UNC name, and cvt to the local-relative name when connecting to the server.)

Does such a function exist?  I haven't found one yet...

Comment: Possible (partial) duplicate of [Get local name of network share in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24576022/11480)

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow up on that thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this unless you can have code running on the other computer where the files are stored. The other computer could even be running a different operating system, not Windows.

So you do have to allow the user to configure the mapping between UNC path and local folder path.

Or write a tool that runs on the other computer and that you can query for the mapping. (But such a tool would pose a security risk)

Comment: I'm confused by the downvote. Would the voter care to elaborate?

Comment: There is a solution in the linked duplicate question. But it only works if you have credentials for an admin account on the other computer.